# Moving Window With Kotlin Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, rx-kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I am trying to create a moving window of data using Kotlin Flows.
It can be achieved in RxKotlin using a buffer, but buffer is not the same using Flows.

RxKotlin has a `buffer` operator, periodically gathers items emitted by an Observable into bundles and emit these bundles rather than emitting the items one at a time - [buffer(count, skip)](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html)

Kotlin Flow has a `buffer` but that just runs a collector in a separate coroutine - [buffer](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/buffer.html)

Is there an existing operator in Flows that can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is not available in the Kotlinx Coroutines library but there is [an open issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1290).

There is also a possible implementation in [this comment](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1290#issuecomment-507073384) which I will also include here:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.windowed(size: Int, step: Int): Flow<List<T>> = flow {
    // check that size and step are > 0
    val queue = ArrayDeque<T>(size)
    val toSkip = max(step - size, 0) < if sbd would like to skip some elements before getting another window, by serving step greater than size, then why not?
    val toRemove = min(step, size)
    var skipped = 0
    collect { element ->
        if(queue.size < size && skipped == toSkip) {
            queue.add(element)
        }
        else if (queue.size < size && skipped < toSkip) {
        skipped++
    }

        if(queue.size == size) {
            emit(queue.toList())
            repeat(toRemove) { queue.remove() }
            skipped = 0
        }
    }
}
```